# How to remove two specific chacters

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text:

```
rule="Aa&~a->c"
```

and I need to remove the letter a that is alone with the ~ sign
so far I tried this regex expression:

```
auxRegla=re.sub(r"(?<!~)\ba\b",r"",regla)
```

the `\ba\b` are to set the boundaries and that works just fine and the `(?<!~)` has the intention to remove the ~ sign, but those two togethere aren't doing anything.

I need the result to be:

```
Aa&->c
```

Comment: `re.sub(r"~a\b", "", s)` should wodk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use a negative lookbehind here, since you do want to match `~`. You can match `~a` directly instead, but with a word boundary assertion after `a`:

```
re.sub(r"~a\b", '', regla)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are using lookbehind for `~`, which will match the thing inside, but will not consume it (to put it simply it will not remove the `~`, only `a`'s that are prepended with it).

Second, you are using the *negative* lookbehind, so your regex matches `a`'s NOT prepended with `~`.

Better regex for you is `~a\b` (no first word boundary `\b` since `~` is definitely not a word character, and `a` definitely is, so it is always true)